# Need help using the pipe command in terminal (Linux / shell file)

Tags: linux, shell, unix, pipe

Doing an assignment for class that needs to be done using commands in the terminal. I have a shell file (`temp1.sh`) created in the home directory, and a shell file (`temp2.sh`) created in a folder (`randomFolder`). When I run `temp2.sh` I need to display the amount of characters in `temp1.sh`. I need to use the pipe command to accomplish this.

So I figure I need to change directory to the home directory then open the file `temp1.sh` and use the`wc -c` command to display the characters. I have been trying many different ways to execute this task and somehow can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated. Without using a pipe I can get it to work, but I can't seem to write out this command line properly while using a pipe.

What I have done so far:

```
cd ~
touch temp1.sh
chmod 755 temp1.sh
echo 'This file has other commands that are not relevant and work' >> temp1.sh
mkdir randomFolder
cd randomFolder
touch temp2.sh
chmod 755 temp2.sh
echo cd ~ | wc -c temp1.sh >> temp2.sh
```

This last line tells me there is no such file "temp1.sh" after I run it. if I redirect to home then type `wc -c temp1.sh`, I get the desired output. I want this output to happen when I run `temp2.sh`.

Example without using pipe command:

```
echo wc -c ~/temp1.sh >> temp2.sh
```

This gives me the desired output when I run `temp2.sh`. However I need to accomplish this while using the pipe command.

Comment: Please show your best effort, and the output you get.  What commands are you using in the pipeline?  What do you get from `sh -x temp2.sh`?  Does that help you work out what is going wrong?

Comment: I have tried maybe 20 different ways, so I am not sure which is my best effort haha. I tried echo cd ~/temp1.sh | wc -c >> temp2.sh

Comment: Only 20?  You aren't being very creative…. :). Please add whatever you think might be moderately close to what you're after as information in your question.  Are you trying to write a script to write `temp2.sh` so that you can run it and get a count of the characters in `temp1.sh`?  What is the `echo` for?  Why redirection like `>> temp2.sh`?  Think about what you'd type at the terminal prompt.  Now write those commands in the `temp2.sh` file and run
 `sh temp2.sh`.

Comment: Well I need temp2.sh to contain a line that when executed gives me the amount of characters in temp1.sh. I guess my issue is more about getting to the directory that contains temp1.sh. So for example, if temp1.sh was in the same folder as temp2.sh (which it isn't) then I could get this to work by using something like echo temp1.sh | wc -c >> temp2.sh. (Apologies if I am not making much sense, I am very new to linux).

Comment: I figured I needed to use echo to send that command line to temp2.sh haha. Maybe appending it with >> already does that?

Comment: How could you do the character counting with use `cd`?  How could you name a file in the home directory?  Even assuming you want to change directory, what commands would you type at the terminal to change directory to the home directory and then run the character-counting pipeline?  You said you know how to count the characters without using a pipeline; can you show that?  Please edit the information into the question — do not continue adding comments.

Comment: Thank you for updating the question. Now you need to think. If your current directory is `randomFolder`, what two commands would you type at the terminal to count the characters in `temp1.sh`? Now, in `randomFolder`, you could type: `cat > temp2.sh` followed by those two commands (each on its own line), followed by ^D (control-D) to indicate EOF. You will then have a script; you can run `cat temp2.sh` to see what it contains. You can run it, too: `sh temp2.sh`. Does it work? Note that using `echo` to create `temp2.sh` is relatively hard. It can be done if you know how; you don't yet know how.

Comment: Maybe you are expected to use a text editor to write your script. Putting things in a file by redirecting output from `echo` is not the typical way one writes shell scripts.

Comment: The pipe is meant to redirect data from one command's output to another's input. `cd` doesn't output data, so you are probably not expected to use the pipe the way you have tried.

Comment: My guess is that you are expected to use the pipe to send the content of a file to the `wc` command. Have you learned about a command that outputs the content of a file?

Comment: Makes sense bli. One requirement is not too use a text editor and to do it all from terminal. He wouldn't know if I decided to "cheat", but he is going to quiz us on how to do it through terminal, so might as well do it his way. Your last comment about the how to use the pipe makes sense, so I will google some commands to output content of a file, thanks.

Comment: When there are conditions like "do not use text editor", state them in the question.  It makes a difference to why you're doing things that otherwise seem somewhat unusual (eccentric).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close to working.  The first part is fine:

```
cd ~
touch temp1.sh
chmod 755 temp1.sh
echo 'This file has other commands that are not relevant and work' >> temp1.sh
mkdir randomFolder
cd randomFolder
touch temp2.sh
chmod 755 temp2.sh
```

All of that should work.  You problem is this part:

```
echo cd ~ | wc -c temp1.sh >> temp2.sh
```

You need to separate the `cd ~` from something that runs some command and pipes the output to `wc`, and get the whole lot stored in `temp2.sh`.  That could be something like:

```
echo "cd $HOME" > temp2.sh
echo "cat temp1.sh | wc -c" >> temp2.sh
```

The key point here is using separate lines for the `cd` command and the `wc` command.  Using `>` for the first command ensures that you don't have stray garbage from previous failed attempts in `temp2.sh`.  You can achieve the same result in multiple ways, including:

```
echo "cd; cat temp1.sh | wc -c" > temp2.sh
echo "cd ~; while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < temp1.sh | wc -c" > temp2.sh
```

And then, finally, you need to execute `temp2.sh`.  You might use any of these, though some (which?) depend on how your PATH is set:

```
./temp2.sh
temp2.sh
sh temp2.sh
sh -x temp2.sh
$HOME/randomFolder/temp2.sh
~/randomFolder/temp2.sh
```